# How to get file name of script passed to manage.py shell?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm running a script by passing it to `./manage.py shell`:

```sh
./manage.py shell < script.py
```

Inside the `script.py` is:

```py
import sys
from os.path import basename
print(sys.argv[0])
print(basename(__file__))
print(__file__)
```

When I run `./manage.py shell < script.py`, it does not print 'script.py' but:

```
./manage.py
shell.py
[full_path_to]/shell.py
```

How can I output the actual name that is 'script.py'?

Comment: You're piping the contents of `script.py` to the Django shell which is why you cannot get it's name. You already know the name of the file since it is in the command, why do you want to print it? Can you not just create a management command?

Comment: I understand now, thank you. The file name corresponds to the database table used for data importing which will be used inside the script itself. I was just wondering if it is possible to access the file name within the script so hard coding is avoided. Now I know it would be impossible for pipes.